# Activating something from a menu strip doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I have a button on `Form1` that starts disabled by default. I have a `ConfigureForm`, where I have a menu strip, with an option to enable the button in `Form1`.

So my code is:

```
    private void Portal2HammerButtonEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.Portal2HammerButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

But when I close `ConfigureForm` and look at the button, it's still disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you create a new Form1 and enable on that form the button. Instead, you have to pass the instance of the form you actually have open.

For design purposes you may want to use a controller class between these two forms. This will help you to simplify the complexity of passing data or actions between the two forms and will give you the power to escalate better the app..

When you open the `ConfigureForm` you have to do the following (in the simplest form however not recommended.)

```
...
{
    ConfigureForm frmConfigure = new ConfigureForm(this);
}
```

Then inside the `ConfigureForm`:

```
public partial class ConfigureForm : Form
{
    private From1 mainForm = null;

    public ConfigureForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ConfigureForm(Form callingForm):this()
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1;
    }

    private void Portal2HammerButtonEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainForm.Portal2HammerButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new form on the click of this button.  What you want instead is a valid reference to the actual instance of Form1.

You have some options available:

1. If one of these forms is the "main" form of the application then you can ensure that it is created first and thus creates the other "sub" forms.  you can override the constructors of any sub forms to include a reference to your "main" form.
2. You can keep references to all your important forms in a public static class such that all your forms can get to those references
3. You add your own public method to assign the "parent form" as a member or property of the child forms.
4. You can use reflection to find the instance of the "main" or "parent" form during creation or display of any child forms.  If you do this, only do it once rather than upon every request.  Try to cache that information.
5. You can read through the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace to find out if there's already a collection of objects through which you could iterate to find your main form.

I'd recommend option 2 or 5.